# Pyspark map function behaving unexpectedly with given method

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark, mapreduce

I have written a class to add values from a 2D list based on an ID column.

The class works just fine when called normally, and the merge function works as intended. However, when handed to the map function of an Pyspark rdd pipline the result errors whenever I call collect or try and apply the reduce function to it.

As far as I can tell from the error it looks like it is attempting to use the values from the class 'diction' variable, but I can't work out why.

```
# To be used in the MapReduce
class CountAccumilator:
  def __init__(self, target, id_position, sum_position):
    self.id_position = id_position
    self.sum_position = sum_position
    self.diction = {}
    # Sums given group
    self.count(target)

  def count(self, iterable):
    for x in iterable:
      # Either adds value to current key or adds new key with base value
      if x[self.id_position] not in self.diction.keys():
        self.diction[x[self.id_position]] = x[self.sum_position]
      else:
        self.diction[x[self.id_position]] += x[self.sum_position]

  def merge(self, countAccumilator):
    # Same as count. Takes self instead
    for x in countAccumilator.diction.keys():
      if x not in self.diction.keys():
        self.diction[x] = countAccumilator.diction[x]
      else:
        self.diction[x] += countAccumilator.diction[x]

def accumilate_mapper(data):
  return CountAccumilator(data, 0, 1)

def accumilate_reducer(data1, data2):
  data1.merge(data2)
  return data1

testValues = [  ['John', 8],
  ['Sarah', 3],
  ['Mike', 7],
  ['Emily', 2],
  ['David', 1],
  ['Jessica', 6],
  ['Robert', 9],
  ['Ashley', 4],
  ['Chris', 5],
  ['Megan', 2],
  ['Laura', 8],
  ['James', 3],
  ['Emily', 7],
  ['William', 1],
  ['Ashley', 6],
  ['Michael', 9],
  ['Samantha', 4],
  ['Christopher', 5],
  ['Laura', 2],
  ['David', 8],
  ['Sarah', 3],
  ['Christopher', 7],
  ['Megan', 1],
  ['John', 6],
  ['Jessica', 9],
  ['Robert', 4],
  ['James', 5],
  ['Emily', 2],
  ['Michael', 8],
  ['William', 3],
  ['Ashley', 7],
  ['Chris', 1],
  ['Samantha', 6],
  ['Megan', 9],
  ['Laura', 4],
  ['David', 5],
  ['Sarah', 2],
  ['Christopher', 8],
  ['John', 3],
  ['Jessica', 7],
  ['Robert', 1],
  ['James', 6],
  ['Emily', 9],
  ['Michael', 4],
  ['William', 5],
  ['Ashley', 2],
  ['Chris', 8],
  ['Samantha', 3],
  ['Megan', 7],
  ['Laura', 1],
  ['David', 6],
  ['Sarah', 9]
]
test_data = sc.parallelize(testValues)

mapped_test = test_data.map(accumilate_mapper)
totals = mapped_test.reduce(accumilate_reducer)

print(totals.diction)
```

Comment: Sample input and expected output?

Comment: Sample input is provided in the code being testValues. The result should be a dictionary containing every name as a key, and each value associated with a given name summed.

Comment: For an array of [["A",2],["B",1],["A",8"]] it should return a CountAccumilator class with a diction value of {"A":10,"B":1}

Comment: you could just use a `reduceByKey` on the `test_data`.